# VB .net property procedure in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, properties

In Visual Basic .Net there is the so called property procedure 
which can have the following look

```
public property Name(ByVal x As String) As String

    get
       return name & x;
    end get
    set
       name = x & value;
    end set
end property
```

What is the equivalent in c# .net. I know c# has properties as well as fields but on the whole MSDN site I couldn't find any reference to c# property procedures.

Any example is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think there is an **exact** equivalent of this notation in C#. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't correct you since i don't know the equivalent :P

Comment: Well the last part was meant for other commenters actually :)

Comment: That code doesn't compile in VB.NET

Comment: It's an example @PatrickHofman the property procedure does exist in VB.net

see => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d65as2e(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Then make it a working example.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I don't need to make a working example cause I already stated it is a property procedure. I gave enough info. if you can't figure it out based on the fact it is a property procedure and the info is not enough then you might wonder if the answer is within your grasp......

Comment: Then remove the code, since it is useless and confuses people.

Comment: @Blaatz0r: I do want to note I actually like the question (hence I didn't downvote) and got an answer myself, but Dai did a good job while I was writing one.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've looked over the code and indeed it confuses thus i've removed the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking about parameterised-accessors (also known as parameterised-getters). VB.NET does support them, but C# does not - at least with a succinct syntax. If I remember correctly, CIL (the CLR's underlying language) does support them, but C# does not expose this functionality (similar to how CIL supported Exception Filters as did VB.NET, but C# didn't support them until this year).

Because C# doesn't support them natively, you must workaround the limitation by taking advantage of C#'s support for anonymous-indexed properties (aka `this[T]`). This works by substituting the parameterised-property with an object which then *represents* the property. Like so (using your example):

```
public class Foo {

    public class FooAccessor<TKey,TValue> {

        private readonly Func<TKey,TValue>   getter;
        private readonly Action<TKey,TValue> setter;

        private FooAccessor(Func<TKey,TValue> accessor, Action<TKey,TValue> mutator) {
            this.getter = accessor;
            this.setter = mutator;
        }

        public TValue this[TValue key] {
            get { return this.getter( key ); }
            set { this.setter( key, value ); }
        }
    }

    private String name;
    private FooAccessor<String,String> someProperty;

    public FooAccessor<String,String> SomeProperty {
        get {
            // Lazily-initialize this.someProperty:
            return this.someProperty ?? this.someProperty = new FooAccessor<String,String>(
                delegate(String x) {
                    return this.name + x;
                },
                delegate(String x, String value) {
                    this.name = x + value;
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

So you can use it as though it were a named and parameterised property:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
// Getter
String ret = foo.SomeProperty[ "foo" ];
// Setter
foo.SomeProperty[ "bar" ] = "value";
```

Comment: @Blaatz0r I have edited my answer to correspond better with your original example.

Comment: Excellent example (i figured it out in the previous answer, before the edit) but it might give others a tad more insight in what is happening. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

'there are two parts of Property procedure First is Set Part (Which is a WriteOnly) and Second is Get Part (Which is ReadOnly).
    'to me The Set Part Satement is like a Subroutine and The Get part Statement is like a Function which returns a value.
    'first we have to set value to its Set Part and second we get value from Get Part  after the value is initialized by SetPart
    'Property Procedure does not store any value so we declare variable to store value.

```
Dim stName As String = ""

Public Property SetGetName() As String
    Set(value As String)
        If value = "A" Then
            value += " Letter is "
        End If
        stName = value
    End Set
    Get
        If stName <> "" Then
            Return stName
        End If

        Return "Empty"
    End Get

End Property
Public WriteOnly Property SetName As String

    Set(value As String)

        If value = "A" Then
            value += " Letter is "
        End If
        stName = value
    End Set

End Property

Public ReadOnly Property GetName As String
    Get
        If stName <> "" Then
            Return stName
        End If

        Return "Empty"
    End Get
End Property



Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    SetName = "AAA" ' here we set value 
    MsgBox(GetName) ' here we get value

    'or 
    SetGetName = "AAA"
    MsgBox(SetGetName)
End Sub
```